# Which computer vision library & algorithm(s), for human behaviour analysis?

Tags: opencv, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, computer-vision, prediction

**Objective:** Detect / determine human actions, s.a. picking / lifting items to read label and keeping it back on rack (in a store), sitting-on, mounting/climbing-atom objects s.a. chair, bench, ladder etc.

**Environment:** Store / shop, which is mostly well lit. Cameras (VGA -> 1MP), fixed (i.e. not PTZ).

**Constraints:**

1. Presence of known and unknown human beings.
2. Possible rearrangement of objects (items for sale) in the store, over a period of time.
3. Possible changes in lighting over time. 
   For example: Frontal areas of store might get ample sunlight during day, which changes to artificial light at night. Also, during night more lights can be switched-on.

**Question:**

1. While I understand that OpenCV is great for face-detection and usable for face-recognition, can it be used for analyzing "actions", s.a. the act of sitting, the act of lifting an object off the shelf ? If so, what are some of these algorithms I should dig deeper into ?
2. Since cameras in stores are mostly at ceiling height, they generally do not have a frontal face view, but mostly a top-down view. I understand that Haar Cascade (PCA) isn't quite usable, but one needs other methods s.a. 3D Head geometry determination. Are there other libraries (other than OpenCV) which need to be used for such tasks ? Are there open-source libraries for the same ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From time to time some people come here and ask for help (or better, code) to solve some of the most difficult research problems in computer vision. Problems that were not solved by the most regarded academics and scientists. Sometimes, they ask for algorithms they've seen in SF movies. Then they leave frustrated, because OpenCV is "not friendly enough".

Now, seriously, if you are a team of PhDs in image processing, working on some genius project, you don't need advice from here. And if you aren't, the chance to do it is really low.

What you can do with reasonable resources and accuracy is to track people in the store: Use a moving-average background subtractor(available in OpenCV) to determine how the empty store looks like, and subtract that background from each frame, to see objects that come and dissapear. You can extract them with the blob analisys lib. A Kalman filter (or a simpler tracker) will help you keep track of the moving objects.

Good luck!

Comment: Have seen something similar in form of product demonstration, but in a slightly different context, i.e. video surveillance, where the product does manage to detect things like "loitering", "slip and fall" etc. With the similar set of constituent technologies (or algorithms), I believe my problem is approachable, if not - completely solvable. I do get the underlying message though and possibly frustration from dealing with people who don't seem to have no idea of what they are getting into (not CV-specialized PhD's) ! Thanks for the heads up and identifying the key algorithms. It's a start.

Comment: I have to agree with vasile, your project @icarus74 can be done, but it might be a little too ambicious as a one-person job, especially if you are just starting in this area. You might be better off starting with a kinect ;)

Comment: @icarus74 While OpenCV offers many algorithms and resources for computer vision, you will not find here (nor anywhere else) a library with the algorithms you've seen in that product demo, for 2 reasons: those people spent years developing them (probably), and they have a big money value. So, neither them, nor others will publish such algorithms. If you want the functionality, you have to research it yourself, and that is "a little too ambitious"

Comment: But, good luck! if you can do the project, you'll be rich for the rest of your life :)

Comment: So true, can't agree more.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty hard problem.  From my private conversations with these guys http://www.picar.us/ I recon they have some routines that detect human actions in the video,  such as dancing or skateboarding.  This stuff is not included in their open source library,  but they might help you if you ask them nicely.

Comment: Thank Vlad. Since there are no open-source implementations and since I've not found much reading material in this regard (probably not searched with right keywords), I guess as much, i.e. this is a pretty hard problem. Will certainly check out Picarus folks, and try asking very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Human action recognition problem is usually treated using [bag-of-words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_words_model) model representation and linear (or non-linear) supervised classification scheme using hundreds of labelled data.

Comment: Thanks Eric. The bag-of-words model is something that I am somewhat familiar with.