# Image comparison against a database of images or keys

Tags: objective-c, macos, image-processing, opencv, image-recognition

I've just spent most of today trying to find some sort of function to generate keys for known images, for later comparison to determine what the image is. I have attempted to use SIFT and SURF descriptors, both of which are too slow (and patented for commercial use). My latest attempt was creating a dct hash using:

```
   int mm_dct_imagehash(const char* file, float sigma, uint64_t *hash){

    if (!file)  return -1;
    if (!hash) return -2;

    *hash = 0;

    IplImage *img = cvLoadImage(file, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    if (!img) return -3;

    cvSmooth(img, img, CV_GAUSSIAN, 7, 7, sigma, sigma);

    IplImage *img_resized = cvCreateImage(cvSize(32,32), img->depth, img->nChannels);
    if (!img_resized) return -4;

    cvResize(img, img_resized, CV_INTER_CUBIC);

    IplImage *img_prime = cvCreateImage(cvSize(32,32), IPL_DEPTH_32F, img->nChannels);
    if (!img_prime) return -5;


    cvConvertScale(img_resized, img_prime,1, 0);

    IplImage *dct_img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(32,32), IPL_DEPTH_32F, img->nChannels);
    if (!dct_img) return -6;

    cvDCT(img_prime, dct_img, CV_DXT_FORWARD);

    cvSetImageROI(dct_img, cvRect(1,1,8,8));

    double minval, maxval;
    cvMinMaxLoc(dct_img, &minval, &maxval, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    double medval = (maxval + minval)/2;

    int i,j;
    for (i=1;i<=8;i++){
        const float *row = (const float*)(dct_img->imageData + i*dct_img->widthStep);
        for (j=1;j<=8;j++){
            if (row[j] > medval){
                (*hash) |= 1;
            }
            (*hash) <<= 1;
        }
    }

    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvReleaseImage(&img_resized);
    cvReleaseImage(&img_prime);
    cvReleaseImage(&dct_img);

    return 0;
}
```

This did generate something of the type I was looking for, but when I tried comparing it to a database of known hashes, I had as many false positives as I had positives. And so, I'm back at it and thought I might ask the experts.

Would any of you know/have a function that could give me some sort of identifier/checksum for provided images, which would remain similar across similar images so it could be used to quickly identify images via comparison to a database? In short, which category of checksums the image best matches to?

I'm not looking for theories, concepts, papers or ideas, but actually working solutions. I'm not spending another day digging at a dead end, and appreciate anyone who takes the time to put together some code.

---

**With a bit more research, I know that the autoit devs designed pixelchecksum to use the "Adler-32" algorithm. I guess the next step is to find a c implementation and to get it to process pixel data. Any suggestions are welcome!**

Comment: You should check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986766/which-computer-vision-library-algorithms-for-human-behaviour-analysis/9988561#9988561 Now don't take me as a jerk, but you should be aware from start that this kind of apps **are not available for free** There are some researchers that put together some concepts, and a few companies, like Google, that were able to make a commercial product out of the theory. You can definitely try something - and SIFT/SURF/AGAST/FREAK detectors are the best out there, but you must count your project time in months or years, not days.

Comment: And don't be confused by the sheer number of web references on the topic - most of them are students that published small variations of the OpenCV example for SIFT. From there to a commercial app is a long way.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to think about your answer, but you're overcomplicating the problem. This isn't a complicated process of detecting objects in a video stream (e.g. webcam). I'm talking about small screenshots, such as of only the text in the "Add Comment" button, and then generating a checksum. It's not far from the applicable stage, autoit users have been using it for a while now, see: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/48333-find-pixelchecksum/

Comment: I'm out here to see if there are alternatives that I could implement on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

A google search for "microsoft image hashing" has near the top the two best papers on the subject I am aware of. Both offer practical solutions.

Comment: And there's me trying to be as clear as possible on the notion that: A) This project is on OSX. And B) I want to fingerprint images that'll allow me to recognise similarity, not completely independent keys.

Comment: Besides, it is no longer in the research stage. At least it shouldn't be. Anyone who uses AutoIT for windows will most probably have made use of this: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/48333-find-pixelchecksum/

But of course, this is for windows (and autoit).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there's no out of the box working solution for your problem. Additionally, the Adler-32 algorithm will not solve your problem.

Unfortunately, comparing image by visual similarity using image signatures (or a related concept) is a very active and open research topic. For example, you said that you had many false positives in your tests. However, what is a correct or incorrect result is subjective and will depend on your application.

In my opinion, the only way to solve your problem is find a adequate image descriptor for your problem and use then to compare the images. Note that comparing descriptors extracted from image is not a trivial task.